# I cannot insert data from jtbable into database(new in netbeans and java coding)edited

Tags: java, database, exception, netbeans, jtable

I have made a project in netbeans where i have to add the data from the jtable into the database..my main class extends javax.swing.JFrame and implements TableModelListener..

my codes are.:

```
public class Extra extends javax.swing.JFrame implements TableModelListener{
     Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    DefaultTableModel model;



    public Extra() {
        initComponents();
        con=DbConnect.Connection();
        jTable1.setShowGrid(true);
      jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(this);





    } private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
     try {
            String sql="insert into item (id,item,brand,model,price,quan,total,qual) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);



            int last=jTable1.getRowCount();
            String column1= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,0);
            String column2= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,1);
            String column3= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,2);
            String column4= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,3);
            String column5= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,4);
            String column6= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,5);
            String column7= (String) jTable1.getValueAt(last-1,6);
            pst.setString(1,null);
            pst.setString(2,column1);
            pst.setString(3,column2);
            pst.setString(4,column3);
            pst.setString(5,column4);
            pst.setString(6,column5);
            pst.setString(7,column6);
            pst.setString(8,column7);

            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data saved");

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Extra().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    // End of variables declaration

    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tme) {
        System.out.println("Table Changed!");
    }





}
```

my codes to insert the data of the jtable is written in jButton2ActionPerformed() method.

now the problem is when i am inputting the data in the jtable and trying to save it..it is giving me the following error..:

```
Table Changed!
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 8
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2560)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2536)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2462)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1300)
    at Extra.jButton2ActionPerformed(Extra.java:264)
    at Extra.access$100(Extra.java:12)
    at Extra$2.actionPerformed(Extra.java:102)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 22 seconds)
```

please help..

**error ater editing..:**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3566)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2113)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1364)
    at Extra.jButton2ActionPerformed(Extra.java:265)
    at Extra.access$100(Extra.java:12)
    at Extra$2.actionPerformed(Extra.java:102)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 55 seconds)
```

Comment: The error message could hardly be clearer. It says that you haven't provided a value for the 8th parameter. And indeed, you've provided a value for the first 7 parameters, but not for the 8th. Have you read the message?

Comment: yes i have changed the codes..but still the problem persist..please check i have edited the codes

Comment: What is the new stack trace you get? The key point is to read the error messages.

Comment: is `id` you're primary key? If it is, don't set it to null. If it's auto-adjusting, don't even specify a `?` for it. Just use 7 instead of 8, if you're not going to put a value.

Comment: @AM26: the error message, once again, could hardly be clearer: "Column 'id' cannot be null". Yet, you're setting it to null. Why don't you read error messages?

Comment: its working but its not saving the value of qual of the last row..

Comment: this problem is happening if i am keeping the last qual selected. If i click on any other column after entering the last qual then its adding everything in the data..y its happening..help

Comment: problem solved..u just have to add a if in the for loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not filling your prepared statement completely. Specifically, you're not giving a value for the `qual` column. Hope that helps!

Comment: yes i have changed the codes..but still the problem persist..please check i have edited the codes

Comment: It doesn't show as edited, @AM26, edit your question

Comment: its working but its not saving the value of qual of the last row..this problem is happening if i am keeping the last qual selected. If i click on any other column after entering the last qual then its adding everything in the data..y its happening..help

Comment: its also saving the empty rows in the database..what should i do that it only takes the filled rows..

Comment: null-checking on the argument?